# beautifulsoup не находит класс при смене страницы сайта

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, xmlparser

```
for item in soup.find_all("tr", 'product-row'):
    print(item.get_text())
```

Добрый вечер! Суть проблемы - нужно спарсить каталог по категориям, данный код работает например на этой странице https://www.electronshik.ru/catalog/bipolyarnye-tranzistory. А вот на этой уже не работает https://www.electronshik.ru/catalog/displei. Ошибки какой либо не получаю, программа завершается без результата.

> Process finished with exit code 0

https://pastebin.com/sg1FcbfA - полный код программы, буду рад если подскажите как её улучшить :)

Comment: Могу предположить что разметка HTML файла у них разная.:)

Comment: Я не мог этого понять, т.к у меня в браузере разметка была одинаковая :) Спасибо, про куки успел увидеть, поммогло)

Comment: А я подумал что ошибся и удалил тот комент :) А зачем вас сессия в функцмй get_product_info? Чисто ради любопыства :) Знаете что такое генераторы списков?

Comment: @СергейШ Что такое генератор списков знаю, в быту не использую) Сессия чтобы не отрубалось соединение от сайта, т.к при множестве запросов сайт банит IP.

Comment: "Сессия чтобы не отрубалось соединение от сайта, т.к при множестве запросов сайт банит IP". Так вот все запросы проходящие через функцию get_product_info создают новую сессию, так вот, в чем смысл сессий в данном случае?

Comment: @СергейШ ну банить перестало xD

Comment: @СергейШ А вообще запросы со сменой страницы ведь попадают в эту сессию, т.е при проходе по страницам новая сессия ведь не создается.

Comment: @СергейШ это мой первый парсер, я не эксперт в этой области, буду рад узнать, что я сделал не так (уверен, что многое :))

Comment: "это мой первый парсер" Я сам еще зеленый :) Что такое сессия? Это сохраннения куков, хендлеров, т.д. между запросами. Простые post, get запросы вне сессий этим похвастатся не могут, да можно посмотреть и сохранить, но зачем если есть сессия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это из-за того что изначально товары с [второй страницы](https://www.electronshik.ru/catalog/displei) отображаются в виде "плитки", обратите внимание на имена классов элементов (`product-cell`):

[image]
[image]

а ваша функция `get_product_info()` перибирает товары только в виде "таблицы" c классом `product-row`

---

вам нужно добавить функционал, чтобы ваш парсер перебирал также товары в виде "плитки",  либо перед парсингом как-то (например с помощью `webdriver`) имитировать нажатие на `label` для смены вида:

[image]

Comment: Благодарю, функционал расширять не пришлось, оказалось достаточно подрубить куки. Спасибо!